# Using Python to take the word count in a single column of a csv file (without using the words themselves)

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to count the words in a csv file which contains the information below, I cant figure out how to use the second column as the word count, is this possible or is there an easier way? And is there any way to use these numbers without the words being involved (ie to do calculations?) Any help is appreciated!

```
a   14
all 7
am  6
an  1
and 5
answer  1
answers 1
apart   4
beating 3
bones   1
break   4
but 7
came    1
cause   2
```

This is the code I have so far but I keep getting errors so I know I'm probably a long way off

```
for col in file:
    count+= 1
    tempcount = 0
    for n in range (0, 1000) in col[2]:
        tempcount = n
        count + tempcount
```

Comment: So you want the sum of the items in the second column?

Comment: how is your csv file separated? you have multiple spaces in this example

Comment: what does `range(0,1000)` represent? What do you have a thousand of? Lines in the file?

Comment: Please add the code that reads your data file, is `col` really 1-based? What are you trying to accomplish with the inner loop?

Comment: yes i need to be able to sum up the contents of the second column and the file is spereated by words in left column, numbers in the right

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like essentially you just want to sum the numeric values in the second column of the csv file.

```
import csv

with open('wordcounts.csv') as file:
    wordcount = sum(int(row[1]) for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t'))

print('wordcount: {}'.format(wordcount))
```

Output:

```
wordcount: 57
```

Comment: for my file this still appears as 0, im not sure why, any suggestions?

Comment: You could try replacing the `wordcount = sum(...)` line with `for row in csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t'): print(row)` which will print out each line read from the .csv file. You should see output like: `['a', '14']`, `['all', '7']`, `['am', '6']`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are tab separated

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('data.csv') as f:
        num_words = sum(int(y) for x, y in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'))


>>> num_words
57
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess of what you are trying to accomplish:

```
for col in file:
    count+= 1
    if col[1] in range(0, 1000):
        count += col[2]
```

It uses [0 based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) column indexing and checks if the value is in the range 0-999.

Using the range like this is not very efficient though. I would check like this:

```
if 0 <= col[1] < 1000:
    ...
```